# Badge component Angular active element?

Tags: angular

I have attempted to create component badge:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-badge',
    templateUrl: './badge.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./badge.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class BadgeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() badge: Badge;
    @Input() cssClass: string;
    @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<Badge>();
    public isSelected: boolean;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    public select() {
        this.onSelect.emit(this.badge);
        this.isSelected = !this.isSelected;
    }
}
```

Somewhere I need to create some badges inline for that I do:

```
<app-badge
    *ngFor="let pagesize of [1,2,3]"
    [badge]="{ label: pagesize, value: pagesize }"
    (onSelect)="setPageSize($event)"
></app-badge>
```

It works fine, as you can see each badge has property `public isSelected: boolean;`, it indicated that badge was clicked.

Problem is I need to have only one active badge in list of badges. Now if I click over all 3 badges they are all selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store selected badge in parent compnent:

```
public selectedBadgeIndex: number = null;
```

Next save selected badge on click:

```
<app-badge
    *ngFor="let pagesize of [1,2,3]; let i = index"
    [badge]="{ label: pagesize, value: pagesize }"
    (onSelect)="setPageSize($event, i)"
></app-badge>
```

In parent component:

```
public setPageSize(event, i): void {
   this.selectedBadgeIndex = i;
   // ...
}
```

But you shouldnt save selected state in badge component, make isSelected as Input property:

```
export class BadgeComponent implements OnInit {
    // ...
    @Input()
    public isSelected: boolean = false;
```

And just provide isSelected state:

```
 <app-badge
     *ngFor="let pagesize of [1,2,3]; let i = index"
     [badge]="{ label: pagesize, value: pagesize }"
     [isSelected]="i === selectedBadgeIndex"
     (onSelect)="setPageSize($event, i)"
 ></app-badge>
```

Comment: I dont want to mess parent, I need to make badge isolated maximum, may be restructure component and pass inside [badges]="[1,2,3]" and build HTML code inside? Then it is like badges list component